# Python MySQLdb works from Python on Command Line but not Django Views.py

Tags: python, mysql, django, linux, ubuntu

I have a Django views.py function named getpos that gets served by apache2 and wsgi.py. If I run the exact same code from my views.py in a normal Python session from the Ubuntu command line, the MySQLdb connection works fine:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",port=22,user="root",passwd="mypassword",db="gps")
>>> 
>>> cursor = db.cursor()
```

If I run it from the django debug server, it fails with:

```
ERROR: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
```

The code that runs is this:

```
def getpos(request):

    query = "SELECT * FROM..."

    # connect to the DB and return nearby deals
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",port=22,user="root",passwd="mypassword",db="gps")
    cursor = db.cursor()

    # Query the gps Data database
    results = cursor.execute(query)
    db.commit()
```

Howcome I can connect from Python on the command line but not in the views.py file with Django? Thanks.

I've tried using "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost", but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Why are you using mySQLdb instead of Django ORM?

Comment: It’s a legacy project I am working on resurrecting. If I remember correctly, the ORM wasn’t able to perform some complex SQL queries I was trying to do. The queries used to work before but not now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change my port in the connect argument to host="localhost",port=3306.